# Null Pointer Exception while trying creating a general object - Android

Tags: java, android, properties, nullpointerexception, android-studio

I have this simple general class where it should give me the width and the height of the running device :
deviceInfo.c

```
public class deviceInfo
{
private float width;
private float height;
private Context cx;

public deviceInfo(Context context)
{
    this.width = getDeviceWidth();
    this.height = getDeviceHeight();
    this.cx=context;
}

public int getDeviceHeight()
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getHeight();
}

public int getDeviceWidth()
{
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    return display.getWidth();
}
}
```

When i try to create an object in my activity i get a Null pointer exception. Why is that? As I am guessing my problem is on Context parameter, but I have no clue how to fix that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the initialization order of cx  to:

```
public deviceInfo(Context context)
{
    this.cx=context;
    this.width = getDeviceWidth();
    this.height = getDeviceHeight();

}
```

The Nullpointer could be in the lines containing the code:

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) cx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
```

where, cx will be obviously null, since these functions are called before the initialization of cx in your code.

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing `cx` variable before it initialized so it causes `NullPointerException`. Rework to

```
this.cx=context;
this.width = getDeviceWidth();
this.height = getDeviceHeight();
```